# 'This program is normally started by Windows' while running uninstaller for Python extensions?

Tags: python, uninstall, runtime

I installed several Python extensions, and now I tried to uninstall them. I simply went to `C:\Python26`, and then clicked the uninstall executable, e.g. `Removeelementtree.exe`. However, I got a runtime error dialog, saying "This program is normally started by Windows".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: use standard windows Add or Remove Programmes.

Comment: Uninstall Python? Why would you do such a thing?!

Comment: Listen to SilentGhost and give the normal Add or Remove a shot, since I can't find any hits on your error dialog

Comment: Plus what Windows version are you using?

Comment: Besides, if you want to take ownership of your question back, create an account on this site, and associate it with the StackOverflow account, in user options.

Comment: All of the python extensions I've installed put an entry in the "Add or Remove Programs" control panel  of the form "Python 2.5 numpy" or something similar and can be removed via that panel without completely removing Python.

Answer (score 3):

You have to feed the installation log file to **Removeelementtree.exe**, for your case it should be:

`Removeelementtree.exe -u "C:\Python27\elementtree-wininst.log"`

The complete uninstall command is mentioned in the log, the file is having this pattern: `[distribution]-wininst.log` and located under your Python directory.

Comment: thank you for this command line! I've been testing a python distutils created installer and have gotten very tired of having to click through 'add or remove programs' for uninstalling every 10 minutes. The other popular command line on the net for uninstalling, `wmic product where name="%myproductname%" call uninstall`, is waaay too slow. :)

Answer (score 0):

If Add/remove programs does not work, try [Revo uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

Answer (score -2):

start -> all program -> accessories -> system tools -> system restore -> choose a date prior to installation of python

Comment: Seems like *way* overkill to remove python extensions.

Comment: @onnodb - Pretty much so! XD